# https Session and posting problem

Tags: java, android, http, session, https

I have an application that needs to be able to post to https with an authentication request and then a register request. Currently i am able to post my authentication request to https and it works fine. When i try to post my registration request to https i keep getting the server response saying that i need to authenticate. I am authenticating before i attempt to register.

**The admin of the server said that i might not be preserving the session.** I am new to doing stuff with android and java. And i am new to this https stuff. I was wondering if someone could help me out here, i do not know if that is the problem for sure or even how to preserve an https session in android.

Below is my code and any suggestions are greatly appreciated!!!! Thanks in advance!!

```
//my helper class
public class SmartDBHelper {

    private static Context tThis;
    private static SmartDBHelper sDBHObject;
    private static String macAddress;
    private static String ipAddress;
    private static HttpsURLConnection https;

    /* constructor, private prevents any other class from instantiating */
    private SmartDBHelper() {

    }

    public static synchronized SmartDBHelper getSDBHObject() {
        if(sDBHObject == null) {
            sDBHObject = new SmartDBHelper();
        }
        return sDBHObject;
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

    public static synchronized void setSmartContext(SmartApp smartApp) {
        tThis = (Context) smartApp;
    }

    private static synchronized void setMACIPAddress() {
        WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) tThis.getSystemService (tThis.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInf = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
        macAddress = wifiInf.getMacAddress().replace(':', '-');
        ipAddress = wifiMan.getDhcpInfo().toString();
        int startIndex = ipAddress.indexOf(' ');
        int endIndex = ipAddress.indexOf(' ', startIndex + 1);
        ipAddress = ipAddress.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);
    }

    /* this function is to authenticate with the database
     * it returns the id_subject, if it is greater than 0
     * authentication was successful.
     */
    public static synchronized int authenticate() throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
        Map<String, String> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.postAction), (String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.postAuthenticate));
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.authUName), "username");
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.authPWord), "password");
        String tempUrl = "https://ipaddress/health_monitoring/admin.php";
        return Integer.parseInt(post(tempUrl, tempMap));
    }

    /* this function is to register the server to the database
     * not sure of return value
     */
    public static synchronized int registerServer(String nameOfServer, String description) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
        setMACIPAddress();
        Map<String, String> tempMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.postAction), (String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.postAddServer));
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.addServerName), "Phone");
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.addServerDescription), "Android");
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.addServerURL), "");
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.addServerIPAddress), ipAddress);
        tempMap.put((String) tThis.getResources().getText(R.string.addServerMAC), macAddress);

        String tempUrl = "https://ipaddress/health_monitoring/admin.php";
        return Integer.parseInt(post(tempUrl, tempMap));
    }

    // always verify the host - dont check for certificate
    final static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
            }
    };

    /**
     * Trust every server - dont check for any certificate
     */
    private static void trustAllHosts() {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }
            } };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            try {
                    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                    HttpsURLConnection
                                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private static String post(String urlString, Map formParameters)
    throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
        DataOutputStream ostream = null;

        trustAllHosts();
        URL tempUrl;
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        if(formParameters != null) {
            Set parameters = formParameters.keySet();
            Iterator it = parameters.iterator();

            for(int i = 0, paramCount = 0; it.hasNext(); i++) {
                String parameterName = (String) it.next();
                String parameterValue = (String) formParameters.get(parameterName);

                if(parameterValue != null) {
                    parameterValue = URLEncoder.encode(parameterValue);
                    if(paramCount > 0) {
                        buf.append("&");
                    }
                    buf.append(parameterName);
                    buf.append("=");
                    buf.append(parameterValue);
                    ++paramCount;
                }
            }
        }
        urlString = urlString + "?" + buf;
        Log.v("smartdbhelper url string", urlString);
        tempUrl = new URL(urlString);
        https = (HttpsURLConnection) tempUrl.openConnection();
        https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
        Log.v("smartdbhelper adding post parameters", https.toString());
        https.setRequestMethod("POST");
        https.setDoInput(true);
        https.setDoOutput(true);
        ostream = new DataOutputStream(https.getOutputStream());
        ostream.writeBytes(buf.toString());

        if( ostream != null ) {
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
        }
        Object contents = https.getContent();
        InputStream is = (InputStream) contents;
        StringBuffer buf2 = new StringBuffer();
        int c;
        while((c = is.read()) != -1) {
            buf2.append((char)c);
            Log.v("smartdbhelper bugger", buf2.toString());
        }
        //https.disconnect();
        return buf2.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: "ipaddress" within the url string is just to safeguard the ipaddress of the server i am using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you probably need to handle cookie headers to preserve the session. If that's the case this isn't specific to HTTPS. You'll need to find the `Set-Cookie` response header when you make the first request. Then every request after that you'll pass those through a `Cookie` request header. Here's a basic example that you can adapt for your case:

```
// your first request that does the authentication
URL authUrl = new URL("https://example.com/authentication");
HttpsURLConnection authCon = (HttpsURLConnection) authUrl.openConnection();
authCon.connect();

// temporary to build request cookie header
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// find the cookies in the response header from the first request
List<String> cookies = authCon.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
if (cookies != null) {
    for (String cookie : cookies) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append("; ");
        }

        // only want the first part of the cookie header that has the value
        String value = cookie.split(";")[0];
        sb.append(value);
    }
}

// build request cookie header to send on all subsequent requests
String cookieHeader = sb.toString();

// with the cookie header your session should be preserved
URL regUrl = new URL("https://example.com/register");
HttpsURLConnection regCon = (HttpsURLConnection) regUrl.openConnection();
regCon.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieHeader);
regCon.connect();
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what i am looking for. However, how do i integrate this into the code i have? I have a posting function, shown in the code, where i post everything. I send the stuff to post from my authentication to this post and my registering stuff. So, how do i make it so that when i only get these cookies one time? I attempted some things and everytime i try to post it gives filenotfound exception at "Object contents = https.getContent();
". I will post some more code when i get the chance, right now i am unable to post it. Just thought you might no something from what i said. TY.

Comment: I have tried this several different ways and none of them are working.

Comment: This did not resolve the issue. However, we scrapped the idea and did something else.