# Java URLConnection Cookie Anomaly

Tags: java, session, cookies, urlconnection, jsessionid

I'm developing an application to login to a page and then access some of the page data.
I login via Firefox and use LiveHeaders to view the session cookies.

I then updated my code:

`connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");`

replacing the "XXXXXX" with the cookies.
The program can then access the required pages.

I am trying to automate the proccess and have used Apache HttpClient.
I can login and get the session cookies via HttpClient, but for somee reason, the following problem happens:

In the main method, I have added
`String cookieString = doLogin();`
and then changed my other method to use
`connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieString);`

For some reason, rhe URLConnection cannot login.
If I copy the `cookieString` string that I print out, and change my code to
`connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "[the printout of the cookie string]");`
then it works.

I have no idea where the problem could arise.
I have printed out the `cookieString` variable in the method before it gets added to the header and it is exactly the same as what it should be.

The cookie only seems to work when it is a static string ("xxxxxx") and not if it is a String variable.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609269/https-session-and-posting-problem/5610494#5610494) is an example I posted that might help you out. It handles parsing a `Set-Cookie` response header and sending it back as a `Cookie` request header to maintain a session.

Comment: Thanks. I can get the cookies I need, and I can set them using addRequestProperty("Cookie","XXXX"); The problem I'm having is that there seems to be a difference between: addRequestProperty("Cookie","XXXX"); and String cook = "XXXX"; addRequestProperty("Cookie",cook); because one works and the other doesn't;

Comment: More specifically, there seems to be a difference between saying String cook = getAuthCookie(); and System.out.println(getAuthCookie()); and then copying the output and pasting it as the String cook = "[copied and pasted from std output";

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference from passing the string and copying and pasting it. Something must be different somewhere. Perhaps the order or timing of what you're doing? You'll have to include more code (like `getAuthCookie()`) and maybe some example cookie values for us to help diagnose.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem. For some reason, the first connection I try using the sessionid cookie always fails, but subsequent connections connects fine. Ive added a flag to tell whether it is the first connection - if it is, then it ignores the error and tries again. Seems to be working - can anyone think of a reason for this?

Comment: Does the cookie value remain the same or does it change at login? One security measure is to change the sessionid after a login or logout. That doesn't sound like your case though. I can't yet think of another reason it wouldn't work until a second request.

Comment: The cookie value remains the same - the workaround seems to be okay at the moment.