# How do I add cookies in a post request in Java?

Tags: java, http, cookies, post

I was trying to get a certain page through java, but with this page I didn't succeed.
Now in my browser it does work, but when I disable Cookies in the settings, it doesn't anymore.
So I probably need to add cookies to my post request in java.

So I went searching the interwebs, but unfortunately I couldn't really find anything useful. mostly it was vague, scattered or irrelevant.

So now my question :
Could anyone show me how to do it (mentioned above^^), or point me to a clear site?

Comment: Can you post your java code please

Answer (score 13):

Here's a simple example of setting a cookie in a POST request with `URLConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/");
String postData = "foo bar baz";

URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "name=value");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
con.connect();

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
out.write(postData);
out.close();
```

You probably need to pass a cookie from a previous request, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609269/https-session-and-posting-problem/5610494#5610494) for an example. Also consider using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "name1=value1; name2=value2");

conn.connect();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.